# Can I turn regular expression processing on/off?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am implementing a search function (in a TreeView) and the user has the option to turn regular expression on/off as well as turn match case and entire text on/off.

Is there some way with the .NET Regex to tell it to not process the regular expression characters? If so, then I could always look for a match using the regex even for the case of having regex off.

One thing that occurs to me. For this case, escape all the special characters in the search string. Is that a bad idea, or does that work?

thanks - dave

Comment: You can use Regex.Escape

Comment: @DaveM - thank you. If you put that as an answer I'm happy to select it and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from your question, your UI looks like this:

```
[Lorem ipsum...   Search: _______________    
    ipsum...      [ ] case-insensitive       
    lorem ...  ]  [ ] regular expression
```

Therefore, you have four cases: case-in/sensitive & pattern/phrase.
To search a simple phrase use [`Regex.Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your search string:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         |                        case-sensitive               |                               case-insensitive                               |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| pattern | Regex.Matches(input, "searchPattern")               | Regex.Matches(input, "searchPattern", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)               |
| phrase  | Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape("searchPattern")) | Regex.Matches(input, Regex.Escape("searchPattern"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Alternatively, you can use `String.IndexOf()` to search phrases:

```
+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         |             case              |                      case-insensitive                             |
+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| regex   | Regex.Matches(input, pattern) | Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)            |
| phrase  | input.IndexOf("searchString") | input.IndexOf("searchString", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) |
+---------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The rest should be straight forward.

Comment: Sorry for using ASCII tables. I was in a creative mood. :)

Comment: BTW - I liked the ASCII tables way :)